# Set Advanced Calendar view in Outlook 2010 with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

How can I set columns, filters, sorting and conditional formatting of an Outlook calendar view using VBA? Also, is there a way to export a view to share with other people and apply it using VBA?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I set columns, filters, sorting and conditional formatting of an Outlook calendar view using VBA?

Take a look at the following articles in MSDN:

- [Outlook Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869117(v=office.15).aspx)
- [Filtering and Specifying Fields in a View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868051(v=office.15).aspx)
- [Sorting Fields in a View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862429(v=office.15).aspx)

You can find a sample code in the [Programmatically Adding a Column to Your Outlook 2007 Inbox Table View](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bali_msft/archive/2008/11/04/programmatically-add-a-column-in-your-outlook-2007-inbox-table-view.aspx?Redirected=true) article.

> Also, is there a way to export a view to share with other people and apply it using VBA?

Yes, there is. You can export the XML markup of your View and then set it on another machine and then apply it to see the changes. The [XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861032(v=office.15).aspx) property of the View class (for example, TableView) returns a string value that specifies the XML definition of the view. The XML definition describes the view type by using a series of tags and keywords corresponding to various properties of the view itself. When the view is created, the XML definition is parsed to render the settings for the new view. To determine how the XML should be structured when creating views, you can create a view by using the Outlook user interface and then you can retrieve the XML property for that view.